# Railway Booking System - Keep count of available seats

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, data-structures

> I want to be able to keep track of all available seats for all trains. Is setting "Train Seats" as a global variable a good approach for this? I'm planning on adding more attributes like price for economy class, business and etc..

```
class Trains():
    trains_seats = {'Blue_Line': 20, 'Orange_Line': 30}
    def __init__(self,train,num_of_tickets):
        self.train = train
        self.num_of_tickets = num_of_tickets

    def book_seats(self):
        if self.train in Trains.trains_seats and Trains.trains_seats[self.train] >= self.num_of_tickets:
            Trains.trains_seats[self.train] = Trains.trains_seats[self.train] - self.num_of_tickets
            return Trains.trains_seats
        else:
            return 'Not enough seats or Wrong Train'

    def return_available_seats(self):
        return Trains.trains_seats


class Passenger(Trains):
    def __init__(self,first,last,train,num_of_tickets):
        super().__init__(train,num_of_tickets)
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
```

Comment: A class suggests there will be one *or more* instances. It seems strange to have more than one Train share the same seats. The number of available seats on a train should be an instance variable, not a class variable. It's also *really* odd to have Passenger as a subclass of Train. A passenger is not a type of train.

Comment: `Trains` seems like a weird thing to be a class. I'd expect something named trains to be a collection of `Train` instances. It seems like the initial number of seats would be a property of a specific train subclass or of a train instance, depending on how you modelled this.